# Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at Port 443 for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I'm facing an error in Wordpress after installing Let's encrypt certificate in AWS on Ubuntu 18.04.[image]

How to fix this issue?

.htaccess sample file for the blog only I'm using Wordpress, Wordpress index page is loading but post pages are showing 404 Error

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Does default apache page work on https ?

Comment: yes it's working

Comment: Can you please reset your permalink and check it again.

Comment: changed permalink also doesn't work, I found the solution I already posted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Get solution for the issue, need to change in `apache2.conf` file after that it will works,

old code in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

changed in to

```
 <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

after that, 
In order for Apache to understand rewrite rules, we first need to activate mod_rewrite. It's already installed, but it's disabled on a default Apache installation. Use the a2enmod command to enable the module:

```
$ sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

This will activate the module or alert you that the module is already enabled. To put these changes into effect, restart Apache.

```
$ sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

it works for me finally.